# In blog rss , how many item show I give?

Tags: xml, rss

I have my own blog http://www.zhuwenlong.com and I set up a rss of my blog http://www.zhuwenlong.com/rss

BUT , I am Confused about the item's length, show I show all the item of my article to rss ? 
OR 
I only need show the nearest 10 or 20 article item to rss ?

If I give all the item to rss , It would to big.
If I give only the nearest 10 article to rss, how could the reader to fine the old article?

Is there some rules of the item's length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20 is probably a good number. However you're right that this means people will not be able to get past/old items this way. You could add pagination if this is a very strong requirement, however you should keep in mind that RSS is 'forward looking': people subscribe to feeds so they get the upcoming content... not the past content!